# python3 socket reading, avoid while True or best practice

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.5

I have to write a simple tcp forwarder in python which will run for ever. I'll get data in 1 min intervals. So do I have to run the `socket.read()` in `while true`?
Is there any better way to avoid all those unnecessary cpu-cycles?
And one more thing, the socket.read() is in a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have to run the socket.read() in while true? Is there any better way to avoid all those unnecessary cpu-cycles?

It's a blocking `read()`. So your process (thread) is essentially sleeping while awaiting the next network communication, rather than consuming CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, you will still need some sort of while True.  The common practice is to put a sleep in somewhere.

If you need to read from multiple sockets, you will need to use the select function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html. This is because the read() operation may block.